# Rails input comma separated value from text field and store in different columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, textfield

I have a model named `RaceTimings` which records the timing of each student in a race.

I want to take the input of the form in format `minute:seconds:microseconds` from a single text field and store the values in 3 different columns of the same model.

I have already been through other links but could not find any solution.

Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

Comment: Scan the documentation for string manipulation methods

Comment: Please provide your code if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `def something=(val)` function which you call all the time when you are using a `=` to set some variable.

```
class RaceTiming
  # unless you dont have those fields in your database
  attr_accessor :minutes, :seconds, :microseconds

  def time
    # returns "12:14:24" as a string
    [minutes, seconds, microseconds].join(":")
  end

  def time=(val)
    #split the val into an array ["11", "04", "123"] if it was 11:04:123
    val = val.split(":") 
    self.minutes = val[0]
    self.seconds = val[1]
    self.microseconds = val[2]
   end
end
```

you call it by

```
record = RaceTiming.new
record.time = "12:44:953"
# do what you need to do
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @huan son . It worked perfectly fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text field is giving the minutes, seconds and microseconds in `"minute:seconds:microseconds"` format, you can do something like this:

```
a = "minute:seconds:microseconds".split(':')
minutes, seconds, microseconds = a[0], a[1], a[2]
RaceTiming.update_attributes(:minutes => minutes, :seconds => seconds, :microseconds => microseconds)
```